# How to select a radio input on ajax callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm going to make a auto complete form. In which the options of the form like address, telephone, fax and department are auto select after a username is selected by a drop down (auto suggest) list.

The whole process is completed. But only one thing - the radio button. I don't have any idea how to make it selected from a value return by ajax. Here is my code.

**HTML**

```
<form id="inst_name">
Address : <textarea name="addr" id="addr"></textarea>
Telephone : <input type="text" name="tel" id="tel" />

Department :
<input type="radio" name="dep" id="dep1" value="1" /><label>Dep 1</label>
<input type="radio" name="dep" id="dep2" value="2" /><label>Dep 2</label>
<input type="radio" name="dep" id="dep3" value="3" /><label>Dep 3</label>
</form>
```

**Javascript**

```
$('#inst_name').blur(function(){        
    $.ajax({
        url: 'inc/autoform.json.php',
        dataType:'json',
        data: {name:$('#inst_name').val()},
        success: function(data){
            $('#inst_addr').val(data.addr);
            $('#inst_tel').val(data.tel);
            $('#hidden_dep').val(data.dep);
        }
    });
});
```

For example, if an ajax returned **data.dep="1"** so the **Dep 1** should be selected.

Comment: All the radio buttons have the ID "dep1", is it a typo or deliberate? But anyway, you might want something like `$("radio[value=" + data.dep + "]").prop("checked", true)`;

Comment: ^ HTML elements cannot share the same ID.

Comment: @MightyLampshade, Stering. Sorry I mis typed, please check again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply loop through them then check the one that matches the value.

```
 $("[name=dep]").each(function(i,v){
     var dep2 = $(this).val();
     if(data.dep == dep2) $(this).prop("checked",true);
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#inst_name input[value="+data.dep+"]").prop("checked", true);
```

EDIT to add the explanation:

The radio inputs all share the same name but they are different html elements, therefore you need to select the input whose value matches the one you received and check it.

To select the radio button whose value is the one you're looking for you use this code:
 `$("#inst_name input[value="+data.dep+"]")`

and then you just check it with this code:
`.prop("checked", true);`

Comment: A line of code is not an answer. Why should this answer work? If the OP knew, the question wouldn't exist.

Comment: @SterlingArcher Hope that's better :P

Comment: @RubenSerrate, I like your method. But it's still not work. Thank you.

Comment: @RubenSerrate, I modified your code from `input[value="+data.dep+"]` into `input[name="dep"]`. And it works but the value is not correct. It select the value='3' instead of '1' which is returned by ajax.

Answer (score 1):

By calling `val()` in the success callback, you are simply assigning a value to the element.

You would want to manipulate the `checked` attribute of the element in the callback.

```
$('#inst_addr, #inst_tel, #hidden_dep').prop("checked",true);
```

Answer (score -2):

by selecting nth radio

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="inst_name">
            <input type="radio" name="dep" value="1" /><label>Dep 1</label>
            <input type="radio" name="dep" value="2" /><label>Dep 2</label>
            <input type="radio" name="dep" value="3" /><label>Dep 3</label>
        </div>
        <script>
        var n = 0;
        $($('#inst_name input:radio')[n]).prop('checked', true);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: All that HTML is redundant. Not to mention `n` will always be 0, so this is not an `nth` selector.

Comment: Of course it IS zero. Is it so difficult to substitute it with appropriate data?

Comment: Yes, actually. This would require a loop to increment `n`, which in turn needs a check to make sure the NodeList doesn't throw an Exception. If an iterative solution is needed, using `$.each()` would be a better idea.

Comment: Any difference between undefined returned by value=x and undefined returned by index out of bounds?